# What is the meaning of Apply in this case

Tags: meaning

Please explain the meaning of "Apply" in the below image.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to ELU. If you edit your question to include the text of your link, you will get more interest/answers.

Comment: You also might want to check out [ell.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answering it relies on user interface knowledge (e.g. *type a link and associate that link with the selected text*) rather than on English grammar, linguistics or etymology etc.

Comment: @Lawrence - I'd rather see this question migrated to ELL than closed outright (just my 2 cents)

Comment: @J.R. Certainly, since you’re happy to take the question. I’ve flagged to recommend migration.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question, because I'm having trouble finding a dictionary meaning that precisely aligns with this usage of the word.

In computer applications, the word "Apply" often means (roughly), "Make this change now."

For example (from a Microsoft Support page)<sup>[1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/285515/selected-design-applies-to-all-slides-in-presentation)</sup>:

> To apply a slide design to only the slide that is currently selected, follow these steps:
>   1. Select the slide to which you want to apply the design.
>   2. On the Design tab, right-click the design in the Themes group, and then click **Apply to Selected Slides**.

or (from a graphical editor help page)<sup>[2](https://help.picmonkey.com/en/support/solutions/articles/16000048983-how-to-apply-effects)</sup>:

> To apply an effect that has one slider:
>
> - Adjust the slider until the effect looks how you want it to.
> - Click **Apply** to add the effect to your image.

or, from a charitable foundation's help page<sup>[3](https://www.hazelden.org/web/public/todaysgift.page?printable=true&showlogo=false)</sup>:

> If you are not receiving our emails, you may have overlooked selecting the option to receive Today's Gift when you registered. To correct this, Sign In to the site, select My Account, then Preferences, click on Today's Gift as an email option, click on **Apply** to save your changes.

---

In the graphic you've provided, it looks like a hyperlink will be embedded after the user clicks **Apply**.

Comment: I believe this sense of "apply" has been in use for hundreds of years -- *to administer to, to bring to bear upon, in order to produce an effect* (NED, "apply", sense 4). The other thing that might help OP is to clarify that, in the context of an "apply" button, grammatically it's imperative. You have described the *effect* you want, and now you are commanding the system to *administer it to/bring it to bear upon* the object to be changed.

Comment: @MetaEd - I won't disagree, although I think that definition is a little obtuse for that usage of the word – especially from a learner's perspective, which is why I was hoping this question would get migrated to ELL.

Comment: We could help with migration to ELL if that's what the OP decides would be best. Until then, it's on topic here and could be reopened if the OP were to add results of research.

Comment: @MetaEd - I was more explaining my answer than readdressing the migration issue. It's a beginner's answer to a novice question.